# React Js state doesn't update

Tags: reactjs

My state is not set in time, or is not set at all. Here's the function meant to change it:

```
onChangeHandler(event){
  this.setState({
    selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
    loaded: 0,
    }
      console.log(`this is the state ${this.state.selectedFile}`)
  })
```

Comment: which version of react are you running? i would recommend you to dive in the documentation for the "new" hooks implementation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html 

Comment: Are you missing a `}` after the `loaded: 0,`?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. There are plenty of other questions on stack overflow that ask about this very thing.

Comment: Other commentors, I think this may be a typo and the `function` is intended to be part of the `[callback]` signature of the [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) call.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll have to update the function. In fact, I saw the solution on stackoverflow and it didn't work neither. I'll set it to the original code which unfortunately gives same issues too.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, as a commentor said. Provide it with a callback and it works:

```js
onChangeHandler(event){
  this.setState(
    {
       selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
       loaded: 0,
    },
    () => console.log(`this is the state ${this.state.selectedFile}`)
  )
}
```

But I have a feeling you've asked this question because you've got another problem...

Comment: Basically, this is a piece of the problem. I'm trying to send the file setState is meant to update to an api, but it doesn't send anything. My console.log obviously shows that it doesn't get updated too; as it always displays the initial value of null.

Comment: @MarvelousIkechi `I'm trying to send the file setState is meant to update to an api, but it doesn't send anything` - make no mistake, your state is getting updated. But now you're talking about a separate problem - you haven't posted any code that makes an API request when the state is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your code.  You were trying to use the callback signature of `setState`, but were actually making the function part of the object that you set to the new state (which should have caused an error anyway).

```js
const {
  Component,
  createElement
} = React;

const {
  render
} = ReactDOM;

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  /* yours
  onChangeHandler(event){
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
    },
    console.log(`this is the state ${this.state.selectedFile}`)
  }),
  */
  
  /* mine */
  onClickHandler() {
    this.setState(
      {
        count: Date.now()
      }, 
      () => console.log(`State has been set: ${this.state.count}`)
    );
  }
  

  render() {
    return createElement("button", {
      onClick: () => {
        this.onClickHandler();
      }
    }, "Click Me");
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return createElement("div", null,
    createElement(MyComponent)
  );
};

render(
  createElement(App),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function to log the message.
`
//setState(updater, [callback])

```
onChangeHandler(event){
  this.setState({
    selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
    loaded: 0
  },
  console.log(`this is the state ${this.state.selectedFile}`));
}
```